# Looking for AutoMapper v2 documentation

Tags: automapper, automapper-2

I just downloaded the source code of AutoMapper to do some debugging. When I built the sources I noticed it has 2.0 as a version number.

I know Jimmy Bogard was working on a second version, with some nice features such as two-way mapping.

But is there already some documentation on this available? Maybe some examples? I don't want to go through all the source code hunting for new stuff and trying out how to use it.

Comment: Jimmy Bogard's blog is pretty much the documentation together with @Cybermaxs (well chosen) other sources

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, AutoMapper is not well documented... There is an official [wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) but this cover only basics features. You will find many tutorials in google. In fact AutoMapper is not so complicated.

Your best option is to ask the large community of users.

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/automapper-users
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automapper